# Promotion of parameters during overloading

Tags: c++, function, overloading, ambiguity

I was studying about overloading and I am completely getting confused with promotions. I looked at few articles in SO ([implicit conversion sequence in function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825867/implicit-conversion-sequence-in-function-overloading)) and I am sure some more are available, but could not find the right article. I was also referring to  [http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~roger/cpp/week20.htm](http://this%20article).
I was looking at C++ Programming special edition by Stroustrup and came across following explanation.

> Finding the right version to call from a set of overloaded functions
>   is done by looking for a best match between the type of the argument
>   expression and the parameters (formal arguments) of the functions. To
>   approximate our notions of what is reasonable, a series of criteria
>   are tried in order: [1](http://this%20article) Exact match [2] Match using promotions;
>   [3] Match using standard conversions [4] Match using user-defined
>   conversions [5] Match using the ellipsis ......

```
void print(int);
void print(double);
void print(long);
void print(char);
void h(char c, int i, short s, float f)
{
    print(s); // integral promotion: invoke print(int)
    print(f); // float to double promotion: print(double)
}
```

I wrote below code. I was thinking that if I call the function with value of 1,  func1(long) will be called because promotion takes place. But I get error message "error: call of overloaded 'func1(int)' is ambiguous". It is not calling the function with even unsigned char type of variable.

Also if I pass call func1(3.4f), func1(double) is called and promotion takes place as per my expectation. Why 1 is not promoted to long int but why float is promoted to double? What integer promotions takeplace?

```
    void func1(unsigned char speed)
    {
        cout<<"Func1 with unsigned char: speed =" << speed <<" RPM\n";
    }

   void func1(long speed)
    {
        cout<<"Func1 with long Int: speed =" << speed <<" RPM\n";
    }

    void func1(double speed)
    {
        cout<<"Func1 with double: speed =" << speed <<" RPM\n";
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        func1(1);
        func1(3.4f);
        return(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard specifies:

> `[C++11: 4.13/1]:` ("Integer conversion rank")
>
> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> - [..]
> - The rank of `long long int` shall be greater than **the rank of `long int`**, which **shall be greater than the rank of `int`**, which shall be greater than the rank of `short int`, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char.
> - **The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type.**
> - [..]

which calls for ambiguity in your example.

As for `func1(3.4f);`, it's just a promotion from float to double, and that's the best match, since the other two overloaded methods have `long` and `unsigned char`.

Also check this [table](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.best.ics#over.ics.scs-3):

[image]

where a subclause specifies:

> `[conv.fpprom]:` (7.7 Floating-point promotion )
>
> - A prvalue of type `float` can be converted to a prvalue of type `double`. The value is unchanged.
> - This conversion is called floating-point promotion.

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller! Well yes, but isn't a double a better match?

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you for helping me improve my answer. I updated, how does it look now?

Comment: That means in case of integer type, no promotion happens and we need overloaded functions for every integer type? Also if I have func1(char) and func1(unsigned char) how can I see if func1(unsigned char) function is called? Probably I need to pass a character having ASCII value more than 127 which may not be possible from a keyboard!

Comment: You could always cast the parameter @Rajesh.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: In most cases only conversions from types smaller then int to int, and float to double are considered "promotions", and thus are a better match then all other implicit conversions.

So counter intuitive - int to long or int to double or int to char - are all considered as matches of the same level and thus are ambiguous.

IMPORTANT: "promotion" in this context has a different meaning from "promotion rules" in discussing a mixed type arithmetic expression: (short)6+(float)78

Long answer: enums, modern char types (w_char, char8_t...) and bit fields have some exceptions to this rule, see the standard or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion the section about  "Integral promotion"